# Install COUCHDB and OPA(Open policy Agent) on SUSE Linux machine

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles, couchdb

I am trying to Install COUCHDB and OPA on SUSE Linux machine. And I am trying to get correct package or repo which could be compatible with SUSU, But I am not able to find correct solution so far. It would be appreciated if anyone can help me to Install both(COUCHDB and OPA) on SUSE machine.

Thank you